# Prove there are k consecutive non-squarefree integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

So, I've got a question for class that asks me to prove the existence of arbitrarily long runs of consecutive integers where $\mu(n)$ is zero.

I've started the proof, but I need a bit of help midway through.

Assume there exists a run of length n, which we currently assume is the longest possible chain.

If we induct on n, we can assume there is a run of the form $m_1p_1^2, m_2p_2^2, ..., m_np_n^2$ (where each of the $p_i$ are prime).

If I add $M =  lcm(m_1p_1^2, m_2p_2^2, ..., m_np_n^2)$ to each number, I get another run of length n.

So here's where the issue starts. When I talked to my advisor about it, he referenced a theorem where there exists a prime $p$ congruent to $1\ mod\ M$.

I am unfamiliar with this theorem, so I'm not sure how to use this information. Any chance I can get some help? Or else is there a simpler way to go about this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Simpler solution: we seek $n$ to satisfy all of the following:

$$n\equiv 0\pmod{p_1^2}$$

$$n+1\equiv 0\pmod{p_2^2}$$

$$n+2\equiv 0\pmod{p_3^2}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$n+k\equiv 0\pmod{p_{k+1}^2}$$

Now we use the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @vadim123 Could you possibly explain this in more detail? I’m not understanding the argument, I guess.

Comment: The CRT will give a value $n$ that simultaneously satisfies all of the modular equations, mod $p_1^2p_2^2\cdots p_k^2$.  Hence, $p_1^2$ will divide $n$, so $n$ will not be squarefree.  $p_2^2$ will divide $n+1$, so $n+1$ will not be squarefree, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are two relevant theorems at play. A theorem that guarantees a prime congruent to $1 \bmod M$ is [Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), which says that as long as $x$ and $y$ are coprime, then the sequence $x + ny$ as $n$ increases contains infinitely many primes.

The second theorem at play is the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), which allows you to skip the induction and directly prove the result.

Comment: Thank you! I believe that was just what I needed. I'm going to give the CRT version a chance as well, since that one definitely seems much more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of induction, how about using the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find a number that is $n$ modulo $(p_n)^2$ for $1\le n\le k$?